# How to accept same timestamp data with multi threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, timestamp

At the first I accept frame data from three devices,and append to one queue,then open 15 threads to read frame data in queue.
I want to accept the same timestamp frame data in three devices.The hardware is synchronized,but you now the operation system have FIFO or other,so the timestamp frame may accept below:

```
serialNumber:85A981 lfFrame seqNo:19-----timestamp:572380866-----camID:0  
serialNumber:62586 lfFrame seqNo:7-----timestamp:572380866-----camID:0  
serialNumber:60686 lfFrame seqNo:23-----timestamp:572380827-----camID:0  
serialNumber:60686 lfFrame seqNo:24-----timestamp:572380866-----camID:0  
serialNumber:60686 lfFrame seqNo:24-----timestamp:572380866-----camID:1  
serialNumber:85A981 lfFrame seqNo:19-----timestamp:572380866-----camID:4  
serialNumber:85A981 lfFrame seqNo:19-----timestamp:572380866-----camID:1  
serialNumber:60686 lfFrame seqNo:24-----timestamp:572380866-----camID:2  
serialNumber:85A981 lfFrame seqNo:19-----timestamp:572380866-----camID:3  
serialNumber:62586 lfFrame seqNo:7-----timestamp:572380866-----camID:3  
serialNumber:85A981 lfFrame seqNo:19-----timestamp:572380866-----camID:2  
serialNumber:62586 lfFrame seqNo:7-----timestamp:572380866-----camID:4  
serialNumber:62586 lfFrame seqNo:7-----timestamp:572380866-----camID:1  
serialNumber:62586 lfFrame seqNo:7-----timestamp:572380866-----camID:2  
serialNumber:60686 lfFrame seqNo:25-----timestamp:572380905-----camID:0  
serialNumber:60686 lfFrame seqNo:24-----timestamp:572380866-----camID:3  
serialNumber:60686 lfFrame seqNo:24-----timestamp:572380866-----camID:4
```

maybe I want to accept timestamp 572380866,but 572380827 and 572380905 in the successive queue.

I hope to aceept 15 same timestamp data and put it in vector,then deal with them.

My code to read in queue with thread is below.

```cpp
//there are 15 such threads
thread_ = new std::thread([=](){
        LFFrame lfFrame;
        int num = 0;
        int flag = 1;
        while(true)
        {

            //read lfFrame in queue
            if(!consume(lfFrame))
            {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
                continue;

            }


            {
                printf("serialNumber:%s lfFrame seqNo:%d-----timestamp:%d-----camID:%d\n",lfFrame.serialNumber.c_str(),lfFrame.seq,lfFrame.timestamp,lfFrame.camID);
            }


            delete[] lfFrame.data;


        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The frame data may lost,so you will accept timestamp less than 15.

Comment: My current thinking is create a queue and map. define is below:   std:queue<int> timestamp_queue;   std::map<int,LFFrame> timestamp_LFFrame;